# Material icons не работает outline

Tags: css, шрифты, material-design, google-fonts

Почему так работает:

```
<i class="material-icons">mail</i>
<i class="material-icons">mail_outline</i>
```

А для этой иконки нет аутлайна?:

```
<i class="material-icons">grade</i>
<i class="material-icons">grade_outline</i>
```

При этом на сайте гугла, если выбрать из меню "Outlined" работает как надо.
https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=grade&style=outline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте гугла они отображают иконки немного по-другому (загляните в сорс).

А для метода, которым Вы пытаетесь пользоваться, с аутлайном есть далеко не все иконки.

Загляните вот [**сюда**](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/find/master) и введите в поиск *`_outline_24px.svg`* - там всего около 30 иконок с аутлайном. Тот же `mail` есть, а `grade` нет.